# Problema carga pagina con ajax sincrono - asincrono

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Tengo un problema que no se como arreglar. Cargo una pagina php con ajax en un DIV y dentro de esa pagina cargo algunas tablas con ajax tambien.

Todo hasta aqui correcto y funciona pero hay un problema, que es que me carga la pagina y las tablas no estan aun cargadas, tardan unos segundos mas en cagar, al ser con ajax que es asincrono es normal.  Necesitaria que se carge todo a la vez o que espere a que esten todas las llamadas completas para visualizar.

He intentado poner async: false en las llamas de las tablas, pero da error como si el Dom no estuviera cargado.  $("#midiv").DataTable(  error datatable no es funcion.

He puesto donde llamo a la funcion de la carga de las tablas  $( document ).ready(function() para asegurarme que el DOM se carga primero, pero ni con esas.

Entonces no se que le pasa o si puedo retrasar la carga de la pagina php a que todas las funciones estes terminadas.

Espero que se entienda, Muchas Gracias

Gracias por tu respuesta , pero me sigue dando el error.

```html
crearTablaClienteGrafica : function (idCliente){
        var objDatos;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: "/wordpress/gsc/formulario-clientes/php/acciones/estudioNegocio.php?metodo=dameTablaDatosCliente&idCliente="+idCliente,
            contentType: "json",
            success:function (datos) {
                objDatos = JSON.parse(datos);
                //estudio.pintarVistaTablas("/wordpress/gsc/formulario-clientes/componentes/compTablaCliente.php", "tablaCliente", objDatos);
            }

        }).done(function () {
            estudio.pintarVistaTablas("/wordpress/gsc/formulario-clientes/componentes/compTablaCliente.php", "tablaCliente", objDatos);
        });
        
        
     pintarVistaTablas : function (vista, capa, datos){


        $.ajax({
            async: false,   
            type: "POST",
            url: vista+"?datos="+datos,
            contentType: "html",
            success:function (html) {
                $("#"+capa).html(html);
            }

        });

    }
```

Tengo funcion que llama   a un php y me da todos los datos de la tabla y luego llamo a la funcion pintarVista que llama a otro otro php que crea la tabla que pinto luego (es en la segunda donde se llama al dataTable).  En asincrono funciona perfectamente, pero necesitaria aque sea sincrono por lo que expuse antes arriba.

Gracias

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio.  Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento estaría bien que nos enseñaras el código y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cargar DataTable **después** de que se acaben las llamadas con Ajax, te dejo un código de como se haria para llamar al DataTable una vez acabado el Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({                    
             type: "GET",
             url: 'api.php',                                                     
             dataType: 'json',
             async:false, /// Esto lo puedes poner en true                    
             success: function(data)          
             {   
                /// Aqui haces cosas con los datos
             }
          }).done(function(){
               /// Aqui se carga el DataTable
               $('table').DataTable();
          });    
     };
});
```

Comment: Le he intentado pero no funciona esta solucion. He modificado el enunciado explicando mas detalladamente todo.